# Building treeview with with deep levels

Tags: c#

I have json file with the following data:

```
[
    {
        "unitId": "0",
        "parentId": "001000000000000000000000"
    },
    {
        "unitId": "1",
        "parentId": "0"
    },
    {
        "unitId": "001000000001001001000000",
        "parentId": "1"
    },
    {
        "unitId": "001000000001001002000000",
        "parent": "1"
    },
    {
        "unitId": "2",
        "parentId": "0"
    },
    {
        "unitId": "00100000000100200421400000",
        "parentId": "2"
    },
    {
        "unitId": "001000000001002241400000000",
        "parentId": "2"
    }
]
```

I want to create a treeview from above json, so if the `parentId` same as `unitId` then make that object as a child.

so far I only have one level treeview with `foreach` and then match the `parentId` with `unitId`, the result is like this:

- 0

  - 1
  - 2
- 1

  - 001000000001001001000000
  - 001000000001001002000000
- 2

  - 00100000000100200421400000
  - 001000000001002241400000000

but what I want is that the treeview is not fixed to only one level and can dynamically add another level without changing the code, something like this:

- 0

  - 1

    - 001000000001001001000000
    - 001000000001001002000000
  - 2

    - 00100000000100200421400000
    - 001000000001002241400000000

I also have read a question similar to this one (link [Creating an ASP.NET Treeview with multiple levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786720/creating-an-asp-net-treeview-with-multiple-levels)), but looks like I can't find the solution from the mentioned link because it's tied with asp.net. Suggestion would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: in the result that you want, shouldn't the child from parent 1 (outside) inside from parent 1 that are inside parent 0?

Comment: Yes you' re right, sorry for the confusion. edited

Comment: I think you should get comfortable with using recursive algorithms, that's how you can build trees with arbitrary depths.